# Comparing directory names with a literal returns an unexpected error

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to compare a variable:

```
DIR=$(pwd | cut -d '/' -f7,8)
```

with a string:

```
NAME="IOPs/All_Brush"
```

My if statement is:

```
if [ $DIR <> $NAME ]; then
    blah blah 
fi
```

This error is returned:

```
line 18: IOPs/All_Brush: No such file or directory
```

What is going on here? I'm pretty sure I've forgotten something very basic but I'm at a loss at the moment. I thought of escaping the slash but that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

`<>` is a bidirectional redirection, not a comparison operator.  You also want to use quotes, in case there are spaces or other special characters, and ideally use `[[`.

```
if [[ "$DIR" != "$NAME" ]]; then
    : do something here
fi
```

Comment: `[[` is not POSIX, it is bash specific.

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html for `[[`.  So, it's something of a quasistandard.  (Actually I think it's not POSIX but SVID; misspoke.)

Comment: `[[` is surely not POSIX. It works only in Bash and Korn shell. It is not part of the `if` syntax, as also `[` is not part of the `if` syntax. `[` is a command, `[[` is just a shell keyword. I don't know if SVID defines it.

Comment: Thanks guys. That was embarrassing. Switching back and forth between scripting platforms has a few challenges for me still :((